# How to create an SQL table for checkboxes?

Tags: mysql, sql, checkbox

Please be very descriptive in explaining the answer, by telling me what to do, and HOW to do it. I have 5 checkboxes, and I want to setup a MYSQL table so I can save the boxes that are checked, and save the unchecked boxes as unchecked.

Here is my php/html code for the checkboxes:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Checkboxes</title>

<?PHP
$ch1 = 'unchecked';
$ch2 = 'unchecked';
$ch3 = 'unchecked';
$ch4 = 'unchecked';
$ch5 = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

if (isset($_POST['ch1'])) {
    $ch1 = $_POST['ch1'];

    if ($ch1 == 'net') {
        $ch1 = 'checked';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['ch2'])) {
    $ch2 = $_POST['ch2'];

    if ($ch2 == 'word') {
        $ch2 = 'checked';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['ch3'])) {
    $ch3 = $_POST['ch3'];

    if ($ch3 == 'excel') {
        $ch3 = 'checked';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['ch4'])) {
    $ch4 = $_POST['ch4'];

    if ($ch4 == 'web') {
        $ch4 = 'checked';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['ch5'])) {
    $ch5 = $_POST['ch5'];

    if ($ch5 == 'php') {
        $ch5 = 'checked';
    }
}
}

?>


</head>

<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="checkBoxes.php">

<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ch1' value ="net" <?PHP print $ch1; ?>>Visual Basic .NET
<P>
<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ch2' value="word" <?PHP print $ch2; ?>>Microsoft Word
<P>
<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ch3' value="excel" <?PHP print $ch3; ?>>Microsoft Excel
<P>
<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ch4' value="web" <?PHP print $ch4; ?>>Web Design
<P>
<Input type = 'Checkbox' Name ='ch5' value="php" <?PHP print $ch5; ?>>PHP for the Beginner
<P>


<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Choose your books">
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

How many columns do I need to have? I am assuming the rows will be the # of checkboxes I have, and will vary.

From what I understand from other posts online, it's a true/false Boolean setup. How do I go about creating a table like this?

Would I have three rows? one for id, one for true and one for false? Does it matter if I make the table columns named "checked" and "unchecked"?

Comment: Why are these getting put into a table? What will you be doing with them later?

Comment: This is actually just a miniature version that is a sample. I'm making a reading list of the bible, (which is ginormous), and I want to be able to "tick" the checkbox after someone has read it, so the next time they go to the site they can see which chapters have been read, and which chapters have not been read. So I'll be replacing the values of "visual basic" with "Genesis" etc...

Comment: I am beyond confused though. I've found a couple tutorials, but they left me hanging at the end, and I couldn't seem to get it right.

Comment: make 3 columns id, description, and checked. id is the primary key, description is optional such as "Genesis", checked is 1 for checked and 0 for unchecked

Comment: If you store each checkbox as a row in the table, you'll have a table which is dedicated to this single usage - which wont be much good if this is storing other than global configuration data. Given the number of checkboxes may vary, I dont think this scenario fits, so I'd suggest using a table with an id, and a single column in which the values of checkboxes are stored as a hashtable. If it can be assumed there will never be more than 32 checkboxes, you could use an int for this, if <= 64, bigint, otherwise use a string

Comment: CREATE TABLE checkboxes (

id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
description TEXT,
checked  .... What is here?

Comment: Your question is entirely too vague. What are you planning on doing with the values you store? What do the values represent (other than whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked)? The proper answer to this depends on more details than what you've posted here.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate the help John Bingham. I'm still slightly confused though. 

Are you telling me to make a table with two columns only? "id", and maybe "value"?

Also, since there are going to be so many checkboxes, would I just have the "genesis 1" checkbox id= 1  and "Exodus 1" would be value 51, and the last book would have a very large number as it's value?

Comment: Thank you Ken, I apologize for not being descriptive enough. 

All I want to do with the values is keep them stored. My only goal is to have a big list of all the checkboxes that represent different chapters. When I read for example chapter 31, I will click that checkbox and it will stay checked. I will hit save, and when I come back to the website later, chapter 31 will still be saved. That is all. Its a simple first project.

Is that descriptive enough? (that is a sincere question)

Comment: @john some people in here are suggesting that you build the database to mirror your application that is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is solvable with the following approach and scaleable, consider the following table structures:

```
USERS  
UNIQUE_NAME (id or something like Woot4Moo)  

USER_DETAILS  
USER_ID  (PK mapping to USERS table)
NAME  
VALUE
```

Now you can insert into the tables like so:

```
insert into USERS(UNIQUE_NAME) VALUES ('Woot4Moo');  
insert into USER_DETAILS(USER_ID,NAME,VALUE) VALUES('Woot4Moo','word_check','1');
insert into USER_DETAILS(USER_ID,NAME,VALUE) VALUES('Woot4Moo','excel_check','0');
insert into USER_DETAILS(USER_ID,NAME,VALUE) VALUES('Woot4Moo','net_check','1');
```

Now retrieval:

```
select NAME,VALUE from USER_DETAILS  where USER_ID = 'Woot4Moo';
```

`USER_DETAILS` has a composite `PRIMARY_KEY` over `USER_ID + NAME`

Comment: There's probably no reason to create *unchecked* rows for all the users..  Seems like a waste of space.

Comment: @MikeChristensen hmm unchecked is not the same as null.  Unchecked means off whereas null is the same as unknown.  So I would argue against your logic.

Comment: I was going by the use-case described, which was to store which chapters in a book have been read.  If a chapter hasn't been read yet, a matching row should not exist in the database.

Comment: @MikeChristensen hmm?  `MYSQL table so I can save the boxes that are checked, and save the unchecked boxes as unchecked.`  or maybe im misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yea, I was reading the OP's comments as well though.  Either way, I think since a checkbox is by nature *binary*, having a row represent a *checked* state and the lack of a row represent an *unchecked* state might be the best approach regardless.  You'd draw all your checkboxes, load the rows and check the matching boxes.  If the user unchecked a box, you'd delete the row.  You wouldn't even need a `VALUE` column either.  Otherwise, every time you create a new user account, you'd have to create n *Off* rows that *really* don't do anything useful.  But we can just agree to disagree on that.

Comment: When I say "save the unchecked boxes" I just mean keep the boxes in the field. Say you have 4 chapters to read, and you read the first 2.
Chapter 1(x)
Chapter 2(x)
Chapter 3()
Chapter 4()

You close out the site, and when you come back tomorrow it looks the same as it does above, that way I can say "oh shoot, I still need to read 3 and 4". That's all I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some guesses about what exactly you're going for, but it sounds like what you're describing is an associative table, you've got a visitor, and you've got passages/books, these checkboxes represent a relationship between the visitor and the book/passage. A normalized version of this database could have 3 tables:

```
visitor (visitor_ID,login/ip/something)
books (book_ID, bookname)
books_read (visitor_ID, book_ID, read_flag --This could be your boolean read/not-read)
```

If a record existed in `books_read`, it would mean that that visitor had read that book.

So, if visitor `a` checked book `1`, you'd insert a record into `books_read`: `'a','1'`
That table could then be used to find all books read by a visitor:

```
SELECT *
FROM books_read
WHERE visitor_ID = 'a'
```

You'd probably want visitors to be able to un-check a box if they mis-clicked, in which case you'd want a third field in the `books_read` table.  The third field could be a boolean data type, for read/unread.  The record could be created when the visitor checks a box, and updated when visitor un-checks.

I'm not sure from a performance standpoint the best way to implement this on a website, but the database structure is pretty straight-forward.

Edit: If going chapter by chapter, you'd need to incorporate chapter, whether it's book/chapter together in one table or separate book and chapter tables.

Comment: That is a huge step in the right direction. Thank you. [I think] that is exactly what I want. I have at least one question on the books_read. 

How do I make a record exist in the books_read table? Would this be a boolean type table with a true or false value? I'm assuming the columns your suggesting are visitor_ID, and book_ID. Does that mean that I would set it up in this way:

When a visitor clicks on a checkbox to "tick" the box, That would assign the visitor_ID to the book_ID?